# Saving form data in SQL via PHP and JQuery consistently fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have been wanting to create a small app to populate a SQL database from a classic form (including select, input and textarea). I'm working in PHP and added JQuery code to simultaneously display it on the page (so to avoid redirecting to the db.php page used for SQL connexion & query).

My issue is that while it was working well as I had 2, 3, 4 and even 10 fields (as I have now), it stopped working at some point and I find myself unable to pinpoint where for hours now.

First, here's the code:

**JQuery code:**

```
$("#dotSave").click( function() {
    $.post( $("form").attr("action"), $("form").serializeArray(), function(info) { $("#result").html(info + " (#" + $dotNo + ")"); } );
    console.log($("form").serializeArray());
});

// Stops db.php from displaying
$("form").submit( function() {
    return false;
});
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php

    // Server details (working)

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $userName = isset($_POST['userName']) ? $_POST['userName'] : '';
    $inputDate = isset($_POST['inputDate']) ? $_POST['inputDate'] : '';
    $sourceType = isset($_POST['sourceType']) ? $_POST['sourceType'] : '';
    $sourceYear = isset($_POST['sourceYear']) ? $_POST['sourceYear'] : '';
    $sourceLink = isset($_POST['sourceLink']) ? $_POST['sourceLink'] : '';
    $sourceName = isset($_POST['sourceName']) ? $_POST['sourceName'] : '';
    $sourceAuthor = isset($_POST['sourceAuthor']) ? $_POST['sourceAuthor'] : '';
    $author = isset($_POST['author']) ? $_POST['author'] : '';
    $content = isset($_POST['content']) ? $_POST['content'] : '';
    $tags = isset($_POST['tags']) ? $_POST['tags'] : '';

    if($conn->query("INSERT INTO dots VALUES('', '$sourceType', '$sourceName', '$sourceLink', $sourceAuthor', '$sourceYear', '$tags', '$author', '$content', '$userName', '$inputDate')"))
        echo "DB: Record saved!";
    else
        echo "DB: Ooops, didn't get through.";

    $conn->close();

?>
```

So I basically consistently get "DB: Ooops, didn't get through." in my #results div.

The last issue I can remember trying to fix was that the caracter ' in the textarea field was stopping the query from working. Then I realized my DB table & columns were in latin_swedish_ci which I changed to utf8_unicode_ci. I have since tried creating a new DB with blank columns directly in both collation settings without better success, so it's probably not that.

I have verified variables were passed properly into the serialized array (logging well into the console) and into the php variables by echoing them before running the query. Now running out of ideas... would anyone have one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
echo "DB: Ooops, didn't get through.";
```

Why not output what the error is with:

```
echo mysqli_error($conn);
```

Its best to only do this while you are in development though.

Comment: Right, should have thought about that one - not too good at debugging yet -.-'.It tells me: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ... and then bounces back the middle query with the variables properly filled in.

Comment: Well, I would say that one of the values you are posting is breaking the SQL string which highlights the fact that your code is highly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, anything posted into the database should be escaped first, in your case this would be - $userName =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $userName);

Comment: Made it! Since it won't be anywhere else than on my local dev before a long time I was thinking looking into security matters later but I did have to escape my variables. I expected the fix to be simple but I just didn't know where to look anymore. Just a last question, would such measure be considered sufficient against SQL injections? Cheers!

Comment: Glad you got it working. Escaping all the values would make them safe to insert into a database. However to take the hassle out it and to ensure you dont forget to do it, it might be worth you having a look into using PDO and prepared statements, An example tutorial can be found here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059